# Authenticate User in Blazor Web App and Call .NET API that uses Graph SDK

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-graph-sdks, .net-8.0

How do you authenticate a user in a .NET 8 Blazor Standalone Application, pass the authentication to a .NET 8 Web API hosted as a Azure App Service, and have the .NET 8 API use the Graph SDK 5.x to get the users Azure/Entra ID information?

I've been able to create the .NET 8 Web API in Azure that can access Graph with the Graph 5.x SDK using its own application credentials, and I've created the .NET 8 Blazor Standalone Application with Microsoft Authentication using the Visual Studio 2022 .NET 8 Blazor Standalone Application template.